# Webpack vs SystemJs/JSPM

Tags: webpack, jspm

I was using SystemJs with JSPM for all my profjects and it feels soo amazing. It is easier as never before to use frontend libraries, with JSPM I can do it in few simple steps:

1. command line: jspm install angular
2. index.ts|js: `import * as angular from 'angular'`

Do Webpack have something similar to JSPM packages manager or there is only one option to use standard npm packages manager?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256204/jspm-vs-webpack-for-angular-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good article to compare JSPM with Webpack:   http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/07/jspm-vs-webpack/

It appears that Webpack doesn't use any package manager.
But it isn't needed because we can simply use `npm` to install front-end libraries into the `node_modules` folder and then require it in app.

Comment: I find JSPM simpler to work with, and also the created production bundles seems smaller (compared to another angular 2 webpack example). Also read my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256204/jspm-vs-webpack-for-angular-2